# Making 10mH inductor on my own

Tags: components, inductor

How to make 10mH inductor on my own?

It is not available in the market, can it be replaced with something else? I have to make a metal detecting circuit using a 555 timer IC.

Comment: Do you mean [you can't find a 10mH inductor](https://www.google.co.uk/search?newwindow=1&site=&source=hp&q=10mh+inductor&oq=10mh&gs_l=hp.3.1.0i10j0l4j0i10l3j0l2.1931.4678.0.7701.5.5.0.0.0.0.211.678.0j3j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..2.3.571.0.o6UTMPpUJhQ)?

Comment: If the 10mH inductor is the search coil in your metal detector you have to make it because you won't find one that is off-the-shelf. Provide more details.

Comment: If you Google "metal detector search coil" you'll get about 1.1 million hits in about  half a second.

Comment: This might help http://www.arrl.org/files/file/Technology/tis/info/pdf/9708033.pdf, it has illustration and example.

Answer (score 1):

Any piece of wire has an inductance, we increase the inductance by wrapping many turns of the wire into a coil on a former. The inductance of the resulting coil will be affected by the number of turns, the diameter of the coil, the length of the coil, the shape of the coil and the material it is wrapped around.

You can find many on-line calculators that will give you the inductance of simple cylindrical air cored inductors. And a few that will give you inductance of more complex arrangements eg: http://coil32.net/

To make your own, you need to have enough wire to make the coil, - the wire must be capable of carrying the current you need it to take, and a former to wind it on.

But as @RogerRowland says, there are plenty of 10mH inductors available out there, and lots of designs for metal detectors, that include the design of the search coil.